# C# Tunnel/Bridge from Http to Socks

Tags: c#, webclient, socks, tunnel, tor

I am trying to use Tor and instead of running privoxy etc client, I want to do it in my c# program ( so no privoxy GUIs). Tor only supports SOCKS right now , so I need a way to send Http Requests to this SOCKS TOR server ( either directly or via a http proxy ).

My program code ---WebProxy ( Http 127.0.0.1:2000 ) --- > Tor (SOCKS 127.0.0.1:5000)-->WebSite
and back

I looked at starksoft, componentspace etc libraries but they all only provide developing clients of these protocols.

SO How can I write kind of a tunnel/bridge so when I send http ( no https for now ) requests
and receive responses ( either using webclient or httpwebrequest etc classes.

I hope the explanation is clear if not please dont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [this](http://www.cknotes.com/?p=204) in combination with [Chilkat Socket](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/socket-dotnet.asp) (commercial) provides what you are asking for...

Another option seems to be [mentalis](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/) (comes as C# source, license not clear ?)

Comment: I didnot understand it. This tells how you can create a SOCKS proxy. But in my case TOR is already a SOCKS server.

Comment: you wrote that the libraries you checked all only supported writing a client... thus I thought you want to write a server/proxy... if that is not the case - what exactly is the question ?

Comment: I want to write a small privoxy kind of Code in my app ( privoxy is a UI based app that works as a Http Web request forwarder to send Http requests to TOR and back ).
I want to use WebClient, HttpWebRequest classes in C# ( or provide HttpProxy configuration in IE/FireFox/Chrome etc browsers ) and write some code which acts as a forwarder of webrequests to TOR ( running on 127.0.0.1:someport )
and get responses back. Actually you are correct that I may need to write a small HttpServer in my code, but will wait for anyone elses answers to avoid that.

Comment: let me see if I understand that: you want to write some sort of privoxy (which technically speaking is a server) which forwards http requests (from where?) and when it receives a response must forward that to where the request came from, right ?

Comment: Myprogram(request google.com) to Httpserver on my machine on port1
httpserver forwards to TOR server-SOCKS 
TOR sends to google.com  and all the way back

MyProgram-->127.0.0.1:1000 (HttpServer I write )
                   ------> TOR SOCKS server runing on my machine
                       ----------->  to google.com
<-------------- all the way back

Comment: so you are writing a http server... how does your program connect to your http server ? via http and without a proxy ? if so then you can just use httpwebrequest... what does not work with httpwebrequest ?

Comment: It is mainly to use TOR for HttpRequests.
TOR is socks server.

Comment: I know what TOR is... I don't know what the question is exactly - how to write the HttpServer ? how to write the request in your program to the http server ? how to display the response in your program (browser control) ?

Comment: Sorry that I am not able to explain clearly.
Basically I want to use TOR from inside my C# program using WebClient class to talk to Internet sites. The main issue is TOR is SOCKS based and WebClient is Http Based, so How can I make a Http Request from webclient so the request goes to the internet site via TOR and comes back wiht a response.
Currently I see that PRIVOXY etc do it but I want to do it inside my program without running privoxy

Comment: that means: you need a http client which can talk to a SOCKS proxy then, right ?

Comment: Probably yes.
So what will be the Communication flow in that case ??

Comment: How can I increase your score as you are very patient and helpful.
I am not able to set more than 1 for answer